# php remove all css display none from string

Tags: php, html, css, regex

i have a string of html that contains css, similar to this:

```
<div style="display: none; someotherstyle: freaky; etc ...">
    Some Content
</div>
```

I'd like to process the string in PHP to remove all instances of `display: none;`

But I'd also like to compensate for discrepancies such as case sensitivity, white space between the components (eg. `display :     none ;`) and omission of the trailing semicolon (ie. `display:none`)

thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What does your sample string look like after replacement ?

Comment: <div style=" someotherstyle: freaky; etc ..."> ... thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be safer to use a parser although you'd still need a regex to find that particular value in the style attribute. Here's a starting point.

```
$string = 'But I\'d also like to compensate for discrepancies such as case sensitivity, white space between the components (eg. display :     none ;) and omission of the trailing semicolon (ie. display:none)';
echo preg_replace('/display\h*:\h*none\h*;?/', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
But I'd also like to compensate for discrepancies such as case sensitivity, white space between the components (eg. ) and omission of the trailing semicolon (ie. )
```

`\h` is a horizontal whitespace.
`*` is a quantifier meaning zero or more occurrences of the previous character. (in this case the the spaces)
`/`s are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), they tell the regex where it starts and end.
`?` makes the preceding character/group optional.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cE1pC6/1

As you'll note in the output it doesn't remove any of the parent containing `display: none` (with the optional bits). So for instance `(eg. )` is left behind but the `display: none ;` is gone.

The `i` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) can be added after the closing delimiter so the expression is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with **sed**.

```
sed "s/display\s*:\s*none\s*;\?\s*//ig" test.txt
```

Comment: The question asks about how to process a string using PHP code - I feel like it may be helpful to tailor this answer towards that.

Comment: Just a note that `\?` usually means literal question mark. Is that how sed expects a quantifier ?